# Display RootObject Class and display it in datatable

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I am a beginner and I need help with displaying rootobject class which contain 2 lists of objects and have them show up in the datatable.
I have been finding ways, but none of them help me.

How do I access the 2 lists in RootObject Class and have them show up in the datatable?

Below is my JSON File

```
{
"Non_Portable": [
  {
    "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Playstation 4",
    "ResourceId": 1,
    "RentalPrice": 200,
    "DeliveryMode": "Hand Carry",
    "quantityOfCables": 2,
    "TypeOfCable": "Micro USB for controller and HDMI for display",
    "Accessories": "2 wireless Dualshock 4 controllers"
  },
  {
    "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Xbox One",
    "ResourceId": 2,
    "RentalPrice": 200,
    "DeliveryMode": " Hand Carry",
    "quantityOfCables": 2,
    "TypeOfCable": " Micro USB cable for controller and HDMI cable for display",
    "Accessories": "batteries for controller"
  },
  {
    "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Playstation 3",
    "ResourceId": 3,
    "RentalPrice": 120,
    "DeliveryMode": "delivery via deliveryman",
    "quantityOfCables": 1,
    "TypeOfCable": "HDMI cable for display",
    "Accessories": "Wireless dualshock 3 controller for Playstation 3"
  }

],


"Portable": [
  {
    "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Nintendo 3DS",
    "ResourceId": 4,
    "RentalPrice": 50,
    "DeliveryMode": "Hand carry",
    "sizeOfScreen": "Top: 4.88 Bottom: 4.18",
    "quantityOfCartridges": 1,
    "CartridgeName": "Super Mario",
    "touchScreenFunction": true

  },
  {
    "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Sony Playstation Vita",
    "ResourceId": 5,
    "RentalPrice": 70,
    "DeliveryMode": "Self Pick Up",
    "sizeOfScreen": "5 inches",
    "quantityOfCartridges": 2,
    "CartridgeName": "Powerpuff Girls and GTA ",
    "touchScreenFunction": true
  },
  {
    "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Nintendo 3DS XL",
    "ResourceId": 6,
    "RentalPrice": 40,
    "DeliveryMode": "Self Pick Up",
    "sizeOfScreen": "Top: 4.88 bottom: 4.18 ",
    "quantityOfCartridges": 1,
    "CartridgeName": "Ridge Racer",
    "touchScreenFunction": true
  }
]
}
```

Below is my code for deserializing json data to rootobject

```
    Rootobject ser;
    string jsonstr;
    private void Booking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      jsonstr = File.ReadAllText("Data.JSON");
       ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonstr);

    }
```

Thanks for everyone help and advice in advance!!!

UPDATE: Helped by Madhi

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /* DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(ser.Non_Portable);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = table;*/
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dt.Columns.Add("NameOfGamingEquipment");
        dt.Columns.Add("ResourceId");
        dt.Columns.Add("RentalPrice");
        // Add more columns
        foreach (var item in ser.Portable)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["NameOfGamingEquipment"] = item.NameOfGamingEquipments;
            row["ResourceId"] = Convert.ToString(item.ResourceId);
            row["RentalPrice"] = item.RentalPrice;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why the table is not showing up..

Comment: have you created your Rootobject with special paste of VS2015?

Comment: Do you mean this datatable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx or some kind of UI/

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi i did not use special paste. Because I am using inheritance because my assignment requires me too. So i just hand coded in the public class rootobject. and i am using VS2015.

Comment: @zaitsman, yes is the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your deserialization is successful. Then you can populate your datatable like this:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Path\json.txt");
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("NameOfGamingEquipment");
dt.Columns.Add("ResourceId");
dt.Columns.Add("RentalPrice");
dt.Columns.Add("DeliveryMode");
dt.Columns.Add("QuantityOfCables");
dt.Columns.Add("TypeOfCable");
dt.Columns.Add("Accessories");
foreach (var item in test.Non_Portable)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["NameOfGamingEquipment"] = item.NameOfGamingEquipments;
    row["ResourceId"] = Convert.ToString(item.ResourceId);
    row["RentalPrice"] = item.RentalPrice;
    row["DeliveryMode"] = item.DeliveryMode;
    row["quantityOfCables"] = item.quantityOfCables;
    row["TypeOfCable"] = item.TypeOfCable;
    row["Accessories"] = item.Accessories;

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

Do the same for your other list (Portable).
This is the result:

[image]

The RootObject class:

```
public class NonPortable
{
    public string NameOfGamingEquipments { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public int RentalPrice { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryMode { get; set; }
    public int quantityOfCables { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfCable { get; set; }
    public string Accessories { get; set; }
}

public class Portable
{
    public string NameOfGamingEquipments { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public int RentalPrice { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryMode { get; set; }
    public string sizeOfScreen { get; set; }
    public int quantityOfCartridges { get; set; }
    public string CartridgeName { get; set; }
    public bool touchScreenFunction { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<NonPortable> Non_Portable { get; set; }
    public List<Portable> Portable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did and added in a additional code which is dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: GridView needs databind, didn't you forget that? Does the datatable get populated?

Comment: oh i binded. The issue now is that most of the json text data are not display. Only numeric values for rental price and resource id.

Comment: I am certain that my json was deserelized correctly and when debugging there are no errors. Not sure why some json data are displayed and why some are not

Comment: Did you add all the columns to the datarow? I have added three of them in my code and you should add the others.

Comment: i am aware, but i am saying the some column values are not showing up. Only 2 columns of values showing up